# HotSwap not working on Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, jvm-hotspot, hotswap, android-studio-2.0, dcevm

I'm making a simple Java project with Android Studio(NOT an android project). I run it with debugger, add a print message in loop's method body, click ctrl+F9 to build it and nothing happens. What can be wrong?

Answer (score -1):

The only found this answer: http://www.badlogicgames.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=20859

- Go to settings -> Plugin
- Disable *Android Support* plugin

The problem is that Android Studio

> ... would create "android-gradle" facets instead of regular "gradle" facets for libgdx [my] modules

Hopefully they will fix this so you don't have to disable the 'Android' plugin in the future for hotswapping to work.

Comment: this option not worked here. hot swap still not working